# Inserting map into database using hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, key-value

I have a table with four columns, say

```
P_Key(int), Ref_Key(int), Key(String), Value(Integer).
```

I want to avoid multiple create statements by persisting a map along with `Ref_key` into this database. Map contains keys and corresponding value.It will create multiple row for that Ref_key using entries from the map.I am using hibernate.

Suppose, I want to persist following map :

```
"Me" -> 0
"You" -> 10
"They" -> 12
```

and Ref_Key is `123`.

Then it should create 3 rows into table.

```
P_Key Ref_Key Key Value
1      123    "Me" 0
2      123    "You" 10
3      123    "They" 12
```

Assuming that key starts with 1 and is auto-incremented.

What is the approach that I should follow?

Comment: It's fairly hard to it that way, and simple to do it if you use a list of objects with those fields (P_Key, Ref_Key, Key, Value).

Comment: How can we persist a list of custom objects without calling create/update multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "*insert statements*" instead of "*create statements*"; I am not sure you can: a database has to receive 3 INSERTs for adding 3 lines in the database. But Hibernate should merge them and send only 1 network request (batching of requests).

The approach I suggest:

- Create an `@Entity` with the table format.
- Create one instance of your entity for each element of your map.
- Simply persist all the instances.
- Close your transaction (I mean `flush`).

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html for more information about batching. NOTE: Unfortunately, Hibernate disables the batching for the auto incremented primary keys!